# Erase keys that contain a single value in the C++ map

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have the following map:

```
void groupIntoClasses (vector<FileData>fd, map<int,vector<FileData>> &classes )
{
    classes.clear();
    for (int i=0; i<fd.size(); i++)
    {
        string name = fd[i].fileName;
        string path = fd[i].filePath;
        string hash = fd[i].fileHash;
        int size = fd[i].fileSize;
        classes[size].push_back( {name,path,size,hash});
    }
}
```

which matches each of my FileData objects according to the field fileSize.
What I want to do now is erase the keys which are associated with only a single value (leave only all the duplicates in the map), but I am having difficulties handling the iterator.

Comment: You mean erase all the map entries where the vector contains only one element?

Comment: What I do here is dumping the contents of the vector (which I previously filled with information) into a map, in order to preserve only the FileData objects, that have the same fileSize(then group them into equivalence classes), if it is going to be easier to do it in the vector itself instead of the map, that would be even better.
For example I have 2 files, whose size is 3 bytes, 2 files at 6 bytes, 1 file at 7 bytes and 1 file at 8 bytes. I would like to keep only the first two and the second three files (and put them into class 1 (of 3 bytes) and class 2(of 6 bytes) and delete the rest.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood you then you can write the following loop to do the task.

```
for ( auto it = classes.cbegin(); it != classes.cend(); )
{
   if ( (*it).second.size() == 1 ) it = classes.erase( it );
   else ++it;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
void eraseSingleEntries(map<int,vector<FileData> > &classes)
{
  map<int,vector<FileData> >::iterator i = classes.begin();
  while (i!=classes.end()) {
    if (i->second.size()==1) {
      classes.erase(i++);
    }
    else {
      ++i;
    }
  }
}
```